# Cannot create store with redux in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Hi guys I'm fairly new to Redux and I was trying to create a store in react typescript application but I got this error message when I used createStore.I checked my reducer.tsx but it's looking fine. Does anyone have any idea that the issue might come from?

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, Store} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducer from "./store/reducer"
import { BurgerAction, BurgerButtonState, DispatchType } from './store/type.d';

const store: Store<BurgerButtonState,BurgerAction> & {
  dispatch: DispatchType } = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

and reducer in createStore got this error message

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<BurgerButtonState, BurgerAction>, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<Store<BurgerButtonState, BurgerAction> & { ...; }, unknown> | undefined): Store<...> & { ...; }', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: BurgerButtonState | undefined, action: BurgerAction) => false | BurgerButtonState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<BurgerButtonState, BurgerAction>'.
      Type 'false | BurgerButtonState' is not assignable to type 'BurgerButtonState'.
        Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'BurgerButtonState'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<BurgerButtonState, BurgerAction>, preloadedState?: { isOpened: boolean; } | undefined, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<Store<BurgerButtonState, BurgerAction> & { ...; }, {}> | undefined): Store<...> & { ...; }', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: BurgerButtonState | undefined, action: BurgerAction) => false | BurgerButtonState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<BurgerButtonState, BurgerAction>'.ts(2769)
```

```
import * as actionTypes from "./actionTypes";
import {BurgerButtonState, BurgerAction} from './type.d'

const initialState : BurgerButtonState = {
    isOpened: false 
}

const reducer = (state: BurgerButtonState = initialState, action: BurgerAction) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.CHANGE_BURGER: 
        return !state;

        default: 
        return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Just as a heads up: this is a very old style of Redux and not what we officially recommend learning at the moment (modern Redux does not use createStore, switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES or immutable reducer logic). Since TypeScript works a lot better with the modern style, you would not have those problems there (also, no action union types etc). 
So, I'd recommend you to go over to the official Redux tutorial and follow that one: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts
I'll also link the TypeScript Quick start: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript

Comment: Thanks phry I have been looking reading lots of tutorials and each website gave me a different direction so I was so confused. Thanks for the recommendation though, much appreciate it

Comment: Yeah, we can unfortunately not remove all the outdated tutorials out there. This is the officially recommended style since 2019 and the tutorial is 100% up-to-date with our official recommendations. Please follow it - modern Redux is about 1/4 of the code of the old style.